# Cast an object into an object from a derived class

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class `Record` that works fine:

```
public class Record 
{
    protected string table;
    protected string idcolumn;
    public Record(string _table, string _idcol, int _id) 
    {
        table = _table;
        idcolumn = _idcol;
        Id = _id;
    }
}
```

I also have a class `Order` that is derived from `Record`, that implements extra methods, only applicable on a certain type of record:

```
class Order : Record 
{
    public void Start() 
    {
    }
}
```

In my application, I have an object `theRecord` of type `Record` that I want to cast to `Order`, so that I can call the `Start` method on it.

I tried to cast it:

```
Order r = (Order)theRecord;
```

but that throws an `InvalidCastException`.

I am thinking that I could create a new constructor for `Order` that takes a `Record`, but I already have the object (which is built by fetching a record from the database).

How could I implement this correctly?

Comment: You cant cast a `Dog` to `Animal` but not `Animal` to `Dog`(unless that animal is `Dog`). More clearer All `Dogs` are `Animal` but not all `Animals` are `Dogs`

Comment: What about `as` operator?

Comment: I mean `theRecord as Order`.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov that won't work

Comment: @VladimirFrolov no, it will return `null`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I got that. But what design could I use?

Comment: Post the casting code you tried and got the error with.

Comment: And what if you make Start - extension method for `Record`?

Comment: @VladimirFrolov that wouldn't "feel" right, as you can only start orders and not any of the other record types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in comments

> You can cast a Dog to Animal but not Animal to Dog(unless that animal is Dog). More clearer All Dogs are Animal but not all Animals are Dogs

```
Record record = new Record();
Order order = (Order)record;//wont work since record is some record not an Order
```

To make it work you've to do something like this

```
Record record = new Order();
```

Then you can cast it like this

```
Order order = (Order)record;//works since record is Order
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I changed my creation code to create an `Order` instead of a `Record`.

Comment: Yeah, that works best if you know at creation time that it's going to be a Record and are not converting it later depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

If you get an `InvalidCastException` then `theRecord` is not an `Order` and you can't cast it.   You could only cast it if it were created as an `Order` or a subclass of `Order`.

My guess is that whatever fetches the data from the database creates a `Record` when it could create an `Order` (and return it as a `Record`).  Something like:

```
public Record Fetch(int id)
{
   // ... get data from db

   Record rec;
   if(data.Type = "Order")
      rec = new Order();
   else
      rec = new Record();

   return rec;
}
```

Comment: Or provide multiple methods for fetching data, i.e. `Order FetchOrder(int id)`, `Foobar FetchFoobar(int id)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is` and `as` operators to make sure something is of a certain type before actually trying to cast it, like this:

```
Record objectToHoldCastedObject;
if(theRecord is Order)
{
    objectToHoldCastedObject = theRecord as Order;
}
```

The `is` will check to see if the object is that exact type or is part of the inheritance chain.

The `as` will attempt to cast the object to the type, if it cannot then it will return null instead of an exception.

Note: `as` will only work on reference types, not value types; while `is` will work on both reference types and value types. So you can `is` an integer, but not `as` an integer, for example.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - ah, just looked it up, you are correct, will make adjustment to answer. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert into a new object, rather than cast it. To do this without writing the mapping code one property at a time, the easiest way would be to serialize the `Record` object, then deserialize it as an `Order`. You can use whatever serialization technique you like (`XmlSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer`, JSON.NET, etc.).

This assumes that all the data is accessible in public properties with plain getters/setters (which you don't in your example, but you should do). If you don't want to do that, you can use reflection to loop through the fields of `Record`, getting the values from there, and using reflection to populate the fields of `Order`.