# Assigning abstract base classes

Tags: c#

See the code below (C#):

```
Control button = new Button(100, 200, "Click Me!"); 
Control textBlock = new TextBlock(20, 20, "Hello World!");

List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
controls.Add(button); 
controls.Add(textBlock);

foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
{
ctrl.DrawMe(); //The objects will behave polymorphically, because they derive from 
//a shared base class.            
}
```

Control is an **abstract** class that I created myself. If I change Control in the declaration to their equivalent derived classes (like you see below) I get the exact same functionality. Why is that? Is there any difference when making an assignment to an abstract base class instead of its derived class?

```
    Button button = new Button(100, 200, "Click Me!"); 
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock(20, 20, "Hello World!");
```

Comment: Does this compile? `TextBlock` is not a `Control`! Am I missing something? Is it just an example?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, `Control` is the class created by OP.

Comment: Yes it does. I defined Control myself as an abstract class just for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: Ah, am sorry. @NewHire thanks for pointing out. I didn't read the question fully

Comment: Polymorphism is a pretty important concept in OOP... If you aren't familiar with it, I would suggest you read over this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When your `Button` class has a property called i.e. `ButtonImage`, but your `Control` class doesn't have, you wont be able to access it when numerate through a control List.
Though, your object will be kind of "downgraded" (not practically) when saving it as a `Control`.

Comment: I just don't understand how the List is still accepting the button and textblock as Control's when you add them, but have not declared them as such.

Comment: Because the Button and TextBlock classes are inherited of Control. It is just a behaivor of OOP.

Comment: Though that be the case, how do I know how to declare both the button and textBlock? It looks to me that in this case it doesn't seem to matter much.

Comment: Hi Dennis, I think Sriram's answer was a bit more helpful to me though I also appreciate you're help; I've gave you some usefulness to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

> However, what exactly is the difference, that is, if there is any.

Well, this doesn't makes any difference when you're calling a `virtual and overridden` method.

Main difference is when you shadow a method.

Let's consider the following

```
class Control
{
    public void DrawMe()
    { }
}

class Button
{
    public new void DrawMe()
    { }
}

class TextBlock
{
    public new void DrawMe()
    { }
}

foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
{
    ctrl.DrawMe();//this will always call Control's version of DrawMe
}
```

Where as this code calls `DrawMe` of corresponding classes

```
Button button = new Button(100, 200, "Click Me!"); 
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock(20, 20, "Hello World!");
button.DrawMe();//calls button's drawme and textblock will calls its version
```

As pointed in comments I'll recommend you to take a look at [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) in detail.

Comment: You're statement, "Well, this doesn't makes any difference when you're calling a virtual and overridden method," seems to give me an answer. The DrawMe-method is overriden as that is required when using an abstract class as a base class; therefore, it must call this method in its derived class. I think the confusion came when you're able to add an object to a List that is not declared with the abstract class's definition, but that regardless of that will still have to call the derived class's overriden DrawMe-method.

Comment: Earlier today I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18701105/2530848) that may help you to understand the concept. Check that..

Comment: I'll explain it this way. May not be correct explanation but let me try. Let's say you have a mobile pouch(List here) and you have `IPhone`, `GalaxyS4` etc. You can place your mobile phones in pouch(List) because it can hold any mobile(Control here). But it can't hold a `MacBook`(because it is not a mobile). Is that clear?

Comment: Very clear! Thanks! I've been programming too much today and need to stop now before I ask any more questions I wish I didn't ask.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped someone today. and don't stop asking questions, ask question yourself then only you can learn more. That's how I always do.:)

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if my answer helped you. You're free to accept any answer which you feel that answers your qustion